# Spring Boot Security without Login Form

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to add security to a Spring Boot application so I thought about using Spring Security. My only problem is the Login Form, Is there some way to authenticate a User by reading the login credentials from a config file instead of letting someone type in the name and password? I want to do that because the application will be running on a Raspberry Pi. What would be the best approach for something like that?

Comment: how does the way you authenticate against a service matter just because you are running the application on a raspberry pi? Do you mean, that you don't want a database?

Comment: We're using data from a database but we don't want everyone in the company to start the project on their computer and interact with the application. My Idea was to create a config file where login credentials are written. So if the application starts, Spring Security reads the values of that config and redirects to the starting page of the application. If someone does not have to config, an error pops up. I don't want to fill out a login form every time and want to let Spring Boot that authentication under the hood.Most examples I found use a Login form but I don't want it that way.

Comment: As suggested, using basic authentication is the easiest

Answer (score 4):

You can use basic authentication and pass username and password in the header.

The configuration could look like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/dashboard/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic();

    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

From the client you have to add the header:

```
Authorization: Basic YWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuc2VzYW1l
```

The string behind Basic is the Base64 encoded username:password